# Capture Media Keys using PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is code with which I trying to capture media keys(like play, pause, previous, etc):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class test(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.show()
        app.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            print('KeyPress: %s [%r]' % (event.key(), source))
        return super(test, self).eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It captures every key, but none of media keys. I also tried QKeySequenceEdit and replacing KeyPressEvent, but none of them captured media keys

Comment: Are you sure this is not an hardware issue? What OS are you working on? I just tested your code and it works fine in my computer (including multimedia keys).

Comment: That is not hardware issue, because hotkeys work in clementine. My os is Antegros with KDE

Comment: Well, I tested it in Windows so this might actually be a bug. I think the key `Qt::AA_CaptureMultimediaKeys` existed in Qt4 but was removed for Qt5. You should consider opening a bug report (which I'm not sure if its specific to Qt5 or pyQt5).

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem: KDE settings. It set my media buttons to its own player controls